# IIS is redirecting to HTTP when requesting HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, https, iis-8

I'm using IIS 8.5 and I have a .NET application under a web site.

The web site is configured to require SSL and it has http (80) and https (443) bindings created with the same host name.

The web application is also configured to require SSL.

The problem is: when I browse to https://mydomain:443 I get a 403.4 error which says:

> The page you are trying to access is secured with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

But in the information below I can see the requested URL is: http://mydomain:80.

Is IIS redirecting to HTTP when I write the HTTPS url? Why? How can avoid that?

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules in your web.config?

Comment: No I'm not. The web.config is actually pretty clean.